# Why is my Chrome extension screenshare window disappearing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am first getting into Chrome Extensions. I have a `browser_action` that uses `default_popup` to open a tiny HTML page with a button. The JS used on that page is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var shareButton = document.getElementById('share');
  shareButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen","window"], (streamId, options) =>{
    });
  });
});
```

When I hit the button, I see the OS window pop to ask what I want to share for a fraction of a second before it instantly closes.

Comment: Probably it's because the popup lost focus as soon as the browser switches its focus to the new media chooser modal.

Comment: I think that was it. I tried the background way of initiating and it worked. I'm going to look into docs to find what would give this away and mark answer, unless you beat me to that @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: In my opinion I would consider it a bug and report it to the dev team. A work around would be to open an actual tab/window instead of the popup, or do the processing in the background script.